# Issue with URL Routing C#

Tags: c#, url, routes

I want to rewrite my urls.

I have a menu with 2 menus options..

When i click on the menu item i want my url to be routed to new url

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("Test", "Test", "~/BusinessVisaRequest.aspx");
}
```

Where as i am getting my old url

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/VisaTracking/BusinessVisaRequest.aspx?mid=6&tid=1&stid=6

Comment: Your routing will rout yoursitename.com/Test to BusinessVisaRequest.aspx you need to put you pattern for the second argument that match your old pages.

Comment: Not clear could u please tell me the pattern

Comment: can you list your URLs old urls and what you want it to rout to please.